# how to extract data from react components in a loop?

Tags: reactjs

I have a bunch of filtering components that developers can use. For example `TextFilter.js`, `OptionsFilter.sj`, `NumericFilter.js`
And this is the code of `TextFilter.js`

import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { useState } from 'react';

```
const TextFilter = ({ column, placeholder }) => {
    
        const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    
        return <TextField
            onChange={(event, value) => setValue(event.target.value)}
            lable={placeholder}
        />
    };
    
    export default TextFilter;
```

Developers use it this way:

```
import List from '../../Components/Layouts/List';
import TextFilter from '../../Components/Filters/TextFilter';
import NumericFilter from '../../Components/Filters/NumericFilter';

const filters =
    <>
        <TextFilter column='title' placeholder='Title' />
        <NumericFilter column='age' placeholder='Age' min={20} max={130} />
    </>

cons SampleList = (props) => {
    return (
        <ListComponent 
            filters={filters}
        />
    );
};
```

Now I'm stuck on how to extract values from these filters. How can I extract values?

Comment: the filter is parse as a props called filters, can u show me the ```ListComponent```

Answer (score 0):

You should handle child's value in it's parent:

**child:**

```
   import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
    const TextFilter = ({ column, placeholder, changed }) => {
      return (
        <TextField
          onChange={(event) => changed(event.target.value)}
          placeholder={placeholder}
        />
      );
    };
    
    export default TextFilter;
```

**parent:**

```
import TextFilter from "./TextFilter";

export default function App() {
  const handleChanged = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextFilter
        column="title"
        placeholder="Title"
        changed={(value) => handleChanged(value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```